# Word for transportation of only people and goods and not data?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for transportation of only people and goods, and explicitly not data?

Example: "On the internet you can't transport physical and material payload like passengers and cargo."

Comment: Usually, physical objects (incl. *people*) are ***transported***, and data is ***transferred***.

Comment: _Brick-and-mortar_ transportation?

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're completely overlooking the [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).

Comment: Well, scientifically, people and goods are data as well. A facilitation to move or displace is to transport and in this case applies to both tangible objects and virtual data.

Comment: @Gnawme: No I'm not. Admittedly, the terminology *transport layer* was one of the reasons I included *usually* in my comment, but to be honest I think you would struggle to find many descriptions of it which specifically use the *verb* form ***to transport***. Mostly they will refer to data being *sent, received, arriving, transferred,* etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is one word for humans and another for non-humans.

The word for humans is *commute*. However, when used in describing transportation, it is intransitive, reflexive verb. You don't commute people, unless you wish to introduce a drastic interruption into their current lives.

The word for non-human is *freight*. It is used both as noun and as transitive verb.

Therefore, *freight and commuter transport*. Like, "The next train is a freight and commuter train."

e.g.,

> The goods were freighted by train and then by trucks to their destination.

The dictionary, as usual ..

> [freight](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freight) (freɪt)
>   n.
>
> 1. goods, cargo, or lading transported for pay.
> 2. the ordinary means of transport of goods provided by common carriers.
> 3. the charges for such transportation.
> 4. freight train.
> 5. Slang. cost; price.
>
> v.t.
>
> 1. to load; burden.
> 2. to load with goods or merchandise for transportation.
> 3. to transport as freight.
>
> [1350–1400; < Middle Dutch or Middle Low German vrecht]
>   *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc. All rights reserved.*
>
> commute (kəˈmjuːt)
>   vb
>
> 1. (intr) to travel some distance regularly between one's home and one's place of work
> 2. (tr) to substitute; exchange
> 3. (Law) law (tr) to reduce (a sentence) to one less severe
> 4. (Insurance) to pay (an annuity) at one time, esp with a discount, instead of in instalments
> 5. (tr) to transform; change: to commute base metal into gold.
> 6. (intr) to act as or be a substitute
> 7. (intr) to make a substitution; change
>
> n
>
> 1. a journey made by commuting
>
> [C17: from Latin commutāre to replace, from com- mutually + mutāre to change]
>   comˈmutable adj comˌmutaˈbility comˈmutableness n
>   *Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003*

Comment: thx, but imho "commute" is more in the meaning of regular swinging between two places. And both, commute and freight, are still two words;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that "transport" for people and goods , "transit" and "freight" too .